# can i backup multiple db2 databases at the same time?

Tags: backup, db2

in db2 9.5 LUW i have one db instance to which i just added a second database. we don't have TSM or multiple partitions which is what all the documentation seems to be about when i search the web for this.

can i run an online `backup db` for the first database and immediately start an online `backup db` for the second database and let them run simultaneously? or would i have to let the first finish before starting the second? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can back up multiple databases at the same time.

Whether you want to do so or not depends on how much impact to database performance you are willing to accept and how long your backups run. You can control this somewhat by throttling your backup(s).

Comment: thanks. i set up a small test and was able to confirm this.